# ASP.NET MVC5 return dynamic type (dynamic) view value problem

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Recently I'm working on MVC5, but I have some problems, here is my code:

```
 public ActionResult Day()
 {
 var q = from o in _db. Orders
 group o by o. OrderState
 into g
 select new {g.Key, Count = g.Sum(o => o.Id)};

 return View(q);
 }

 So there is code in the controller, view layer:

 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
       <td>@item.Key</td>
 }
```

VS exception: "object" does not contain the definition of "Key", but if you display @item directly, it will display {Key=ABC,Count=12}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to think the problem is complicated, why not instantiate an ExpandoObject directly.

Please refer to [ExpandoObject Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-7.0), ExpandoObject() can dynamically add and delete its member object

```
dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
```

or directly via

```
dynamic d = new {p1 = "", p2 = "", p3 = ""}
```